# Symfony Form + EntityType Field + oTm > mTo < oTm relation = wrong type when saving

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a tagging system set as `OneToMany ManyToOne OneToMany` like this:

ITEM `OneToMany` to TAGS

TAGS `ManyToOne` to TAG and ITEM

TAG `OneToMany` to TAGS

The ITEM form field to this relation is `EntityType` from `TAG` so I have a list of my available tags from the database to choose from

When I save my form I am getting `Expected value of type "App\Entity\tags" for association field "App\Entity\Item#$tags", got "App\Entity\Tag" instead.`

I don't understand because I am using `EntityType` so Doctrine should know this is a relation and automatically create the `TAGS` object ? How do I tell Symfony to automatically convert my `TAG` object to `TAGS` relation object ?

Am I supposed to do a `CollectionType` instead ? That seems inappropriate in this case...

here is my form TYPE:

```
->add('tags', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => \App\Entity\Tag::class,
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
              return $er->createQueryBuilder('tag')
               ->orderBy('tag.name', 'ASC');
         },
         'expanded' => true ,
         'multiple' => true,
   ))
```

ITEM ENTITY

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="tags", mappedBy="item")
 */
private $tags;
```

TAGS ENTITY

```
 /**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Item", inversedBy="tags")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="item_id")
 */
private $item;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="items")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $tag;
```

TAG ENTITY

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="tags", mappedBy="tag")
 *
 */
private $items;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to embed the second form as Collection Type then add allow_add if you want to add new tags to your entity ITEM:

```
$builder->add('tags', CollectionType::class, array(
        'entry_type' => TagType::class,
        'entry_options' => array('label' => false),
        'allow_add' => true,
    ));
```

check the docs [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype)